# Selection changed event of ComboBoxEditSettings in a Devexpress gridcontrol(Silverlight)

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, devexpress

I am doin silverlight 4 App.

I  have devexpress gridcontrol of 5 columns where i have placed ComboBoxEditor in a column .

```
<dxg:GridControl x:Name="grid_currentillnes">
                            <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Complaints" Header="Complaints/Disease" />
                                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Duration" Header="Duratiion" />
                                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Period" Header="Period" />
                                <dxg:GridColumn Header="Treatment" FieldName="Treatment">
                                    <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                                        <dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings x:Name="cmbx_treatmenttype" PopupMaxHeight="150"  DisplayMember="Treatment" ValueMember="Treatment"  />
                                    </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                                </dxg:GridColumn>
                                <dxg:GridColumn Header="Details" FieldName="Details" />
                            </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                            <dxg:GridControl.View>
                                <dxg:TableView Name="tableView4" ShowGroupPanel="False"  NewItemRowPosition="Top" NavigationStyle="Cell"  />
                            </dxg:GridControl.View>
                        </dxg:GridControl>
```

I want get the **selection changed event of the combobox editor** but no such event exist..How is this done??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is only one editor at one time when View is in the editing mode. After this editor has been shown, a View fires the [GridViewBase.ShownEditor](http://help.devexpress.com/Silverlight/DevExpressXpfGridGridViewBase_ShownEditortopic.aspx) event. So you can use this event to subscribe any event(e.g [ComboBoxEdit.SelectedIndexChanged](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#Silverlight/DevExpressXpfEditorsLookUpEditBase_SelectedIndexChangedtopic)) of active editor ([GridViewBase.ActiveEditor](http://help.devexpress.com/#Silverlight/DevExpressXpfGridDataViewBase_ActiveEditortopic)). To unsubscribe the event you can use the [GridViewBase.HiddenEditor](http://help.devexpress.com/Silverlight/DevExpressXpfGridGridViewBase_HiddenEditortopic.aspx):

```
tableView3.ShownEditor += new EditorEventHandler(tableView3_ShownEditor);
tableView3.HiddenEditor += new EditorEventHandler(tableView3_HiddenEditor);
//...
void tableView3_ShownEditor(object sender, EditorEventArgs e) {
    if(e.Column.FieldName == "Treatment") {
        ((ComboBoxEdit)tableView3.ActiveEditor).SelectedIndexChanged += ComboBoxEdit_SelectedIndexChanged;
    }
}
void tableView3_HiddenEditor(object sender, EditorEventArgs e) {
    if(e.Column.FieldName == "Treatment") {
        ((ComboBoxEdit)tableView3.ActiveEditor).SelectedIndexChanged -= ComboBoxEdit_SelectedIndexChanged;
    }
}
void ComboBoxEdit_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    // do something
}
```