# XAML - Show message box when combobox item selected

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, devexpress

I have a combo box in the ribbon of the window. I wanted to know how can I show message box when each of the item is selected.

```
<dxr:RibbonPageGroup Caption="Type">
    <dxb:BarEditItem x:Name="BarEditItem2" EditHeight="20" EditWidth="120" >
        <dxb:BarEditItem.EditSettings>
            <dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings PopupMaxWidth="150" PopupMaxHeight="50" Name="comboBox1">
                <dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings.Items >
                    <system:String>Item1</system:String>
                    <system:String>Item2</system:String>
                </dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings.Items>
            </dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings>
        </dxb:BarEditItem.EditSettings>
    </dxb:BarEditItem>
</dxr:RibbonPageGroup>
```

Can anyone please tell me how to perform this operation?

Comment: look if it can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510679/selection-changed-event-of-comboboxeditsettings-in-a-devexpress-gridcontrolsilv

Comment: I can add it to the ComboBoxEditSettings but I am not sure how to add it to the ComboBoxEditSettings.Item, because I want to display message box only when I select either of the 2 items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to set the control template instead of using the EditSettings, then you can add event handlers for the ComboBox

```
<dxb:BarEditItem.EditTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <dxe:ComboBoxEdit x:Name="PART_Editor"
                          SelectedIndexChanged="OnSelectedIndexChanged">
            <dxe:ComboBoxEdit.Items>
                <system:String>Item1</system:String>
                <system:String>Item2</system:String>
            </dxe:ComboBoxEdit.Items>
        </dxe:ComboBoxEdit>
    </DataTemplate>
</dxb:BarEditItem.EditTemplate>
```

Handler

```
public void OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
    MessageBox.Show("");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But I am getting an error regarding ControlTemplate - Invalid Type: expected type is 'DependencyProperty', actual type is 'ControlTemplate' .  Can I please know how to fix it?

Comment: What if you change ControlTemplate to DataTemplate?